# Authorization filter in ASP.NET API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a Authorization filter, In access token we have a condition.
Below is ex.

```
 public class accessToken
 {
     public string Condition{get;set;}
 }
```

Condition contains value eg: `Id EQ '123' or name EQ 'rob' or marks in (60,80)`
Ex.

```
Class student
{
     Int Id {get; set;}
     String name {get; set;}
     Double marks { get; set;}
}
```

Now we have an api endpoint

```
Endpoint: GET Student/{StudentId}
```

AccessToken contains condition
Ex:
 `"condition": "Id eq '123'"`

Here condition should be satisfied.
Here I can check with URI `if studentId == Id("123")` in authorization filter.
But if condition is `name eq 'abc'`  then I have to fetched data from db and then verify name is equal to abc. I am not able to find common code for both condition in authorizationFilter.

Comment: where is authorization filter code ?

Comment: When the property is `Id` or `name` in Condition, you can just use `==` to do judgment, But when the property is `marks`, You can't use `==` to do judgment, So it's difficult to create a common code for both condition. I think you need to spilt Condition and 
Predefine some judgment conditions based on the value in Condition ，like `eq` is `==` in linq, `in` is `contains(xx)` in linq, Then add different judgment conditions according to the different values in accessToken.